# Bounded types: Multiple bounds

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, bounded-types

I have read this article [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) and tried to figure out how to work with bound types. What I try to achieve is a parametrized method that handles four different cases:

- T extends B only
- T extends B and I (here D)
- T extends I only
- everything else

So here is the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        B b = new B();
        D d = new D();
        I i = new I() {
        };
        handle("aaasd");
        handle(b);
        handle(d); <---- Problem 1
        handle(i);
    }

    public static class B {

    }

    public static interface I {

    }

    public static class D extends B implements I {

    }


    public static <T> void handle(T objT) {
        System.out.println("T");
    }

    private static <T extends B> void handle(T obj) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

    public static <T extends B & I> void handle(T objT) { <--- Problem 2
        System.out.println("B+I");
    }

    private static <T extends I> void handle(T obj) {
        System.out.println("I");
    }
}
```

The compiler complains and says two things:

1. Ambiguous call

   > The method handle(Main.D) is ambiguous for the type Main
   >   I guess the problem is caused by the same cause as Problem number 2. The & I clearly bounds the type of T to a subtype of B AND I thus removing ambiguity in my opinion.
2. Same erasure handle

   > Method handle(T) has the same erasure handle(Main.B) as another method in type Main
   >   My guess is that this is the real cause for all the problems. Java somehow removes bounding to I during runtime? But when I call the method with type B this doesn't call the annoted method.

Can someone explain how I fix the problem/distinguish between B, B&I and I?

Comment: If you want all 3 of the last `handle` methods, you can't fix it.

Comment: Is there another method to do this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a concept known as type erasure that applies to all generics in Java. With generic methods, after compilation, the methods in the byte code appear as their erasure, so

```
public static <T> void handle(T objT) {
    System.out.println("T");
}

private static <T extends B> void handle(T obj) {
    System.out.println("B");
}

public static <T extends B & I> void handle(T objT) { <--- Problem 2
    System.out.println("B+I");
}

private static <T extends I> void handle(T obj) {
    System.out.println("I");
}
```

actually become

```
public static void handle(Object objT) {
    System.out.println("T");
}

private static void handle(B obj) {
    System.out.println("B");
}

public static void handle(B objT) { 
    System.out.println("B+I");
}

private static void handle(I obj) {
    System.out.println("I");
}
```

The left-most bound of a type variable is what a parameter of that type gets replaced with. As you can see, both your 2nd and 3rd method have the same name and same parameter types, ie. the same signature. This cannot be allowed by the compiler.

However, the syntax of bounds forces you to provide the class type before any interface types so

```
<T extends I & B>
```

wouldn't work. It also wouldn't work because your 4th method would again have the same erasure.

Additionally, invoking

```
handle(d);
```

is a problem since both the 2nd and 4th method could handle it, none is more specific. This is known as overloading ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

> Java somehow removes bounding to I during runtime?

No, Java removes *every* type information at runtime (except for reflection purposes) which is called type erasure.

Using bounds the compiler would be able to translate your code to `handle(Object)`, `handle(B)` and `handle(I)` but in the `T extends B & I` case the compiler would get conflicts.

AFAIK, there's no way to fix this without having a common bound, e.g. `T extends D` instead of `T extends B & I` where `D extends B implements I` or to change the method name or add another parameter.

Another way might be to add the logic in the B+I case to either the B or I method and check for the second condition inside, e.g.

```
private static <T extends B> void handle(T obj) {
    if( obj instanceof I) { 
      System.out.println("B+I");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: Java why you do this to my... Thanks though. And checking inside the method is not really a very good option. The user may decide "treat this as `B` and not as `B & I`. And my problem with common bound is that I want to accept objects from an inplace API that doesn't have these common types. (Maybe new coding standard? Always make an abstract class that acts as a common type, kind of like bound-groups?)

Comment: @WorldSEnder well there's a lot of people who think that Java Generics miss a lot but there's always the backwards compatibility problem which makes it hard to get right for everyone. If it is an API and the user should be able to decide which one to call, you could just rename the method or only provide `handle(B)` and `handle(I)` and whenever the user passes in an object that would apply to both, let the caller decide by using a cast.